SimpleSAMLphp installing not showing admin page but welcome page
I have configured latest simplesamlphp2.2.2 with php 8.1.2. following https://buckbeak99.medium.com/a-step-by-step-guide-to-configuring-simplesamlphp-bcd2dbd2b2b4
but i am getting following message on my front end instead of admin page. What could be possible reason for this?
This is the front page of the SimpleSAMLphp authentication software. There's not much to see here.
If you are the administrator of this installation, please refer to the SimpleSAMLphp documentation for how to configure and interact with the software.
I am expecting admin page in my front-end browser window

Don't just refer to the article - that article could vanish one day. Provide a minimum reproducible example, and describe the exact steps that you have taken.
